# How to increase space in Y axis label in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have run this R script to get a bubble chart

```r
library(reader)

data <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\class.csv", header=TRUE,sep=",", stringsAsFact=FALSE)
sizeRange <- c(0,20)
library(ggrepel)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x=0,y=Class,label=Class)) + 
  geom_text_repel(nudge_x=-0.5,size=0.2,show.legend = F)+
  geom_point(aes(size = Total),colour="green",stroke=2,alpha = 0.5)+ 
  scale_size(range = sizeRange)+ 
  theme_bw() + 
          theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
                panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
                axis.line = element_line(colour = "white"))

dput(data)
structure(list(Class = c("Acidobacteriia", "Actinomycetia", "Armatimonadia", 
"Chthonomonadetes", "Bacteroidia", "Flavobacteriia", "Bacteroidetes-NA", 
"Chloroflexia", "Dehalococcoidia", "Thermomicrobia", "Cyano-NA-1", 
"Cyano-NA-2", "Deinococci", "Bacilli", "Planctomycetia", "Acidithiobacillia", 
"Alphaproteobacteria", "Betaproteobacteria", "Deltaproteobacteria", 
"Epsilonproteobacteria", "Gammaproteobacteria", "Hydrogenophilalia", 
"Oligoflexia", "Spirochaetia", "Synergistia", "Verrucomicrobiae", 
"Thermoprotei", "Halobacteria", "Methanobacteria", "Methanomicrobia", 
"Thermococci", "Nitrososphaeria", "Thaumarchaeota-NA"), Total = c(131L, 
24266L, 2L, 62L, 6822L, 3235L, 0L, 77L, 63L, 18L, 0L, 0L, 289L, 
61290L, 292L, 110L, 14495L, 14472L, 1278L, 7123L, 110632L, 18L, 
96L, 2019L, 103L, 509L, 339L, 550L, 480L, 528L, 103L, 34L, 0L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -33L))
```

I want to increase the space between the bubbles so that they can look distinct, more clear, and non-overlapping.

[image]

alpha = 0.5
[image]

Comment: Please include sample data in your question to reproduce the problem. you can get it by running `dput(data)` from RConsole.

Comment: What about using the `alpha` parameter? For instance, `geom_point(aes(size = Total), colour="blue",stroke=1, alpha = 0.5)`. Increasing the space of y axis can be done otherwise by increasing the size of your plot device.

Comment: @Maël thank you for your suggestion, I have tried using alpha = 0.5, but it just made my bubble more transparent, it decreases its solid color. I have added the plot in the question.